# Help with setting up a configuration file and running a code

Tags: 16.04, apt, compiling, configuration, boost

I'm fairly new to linux and trying to get some code to run. After trying for a few days without success, I hope someone can help me. My Linux version is

> Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS Release: 16.04 Codename: xenial

The code is found here: https://bitbucket.org/dsign/gecmi/wiki/Home

My problems lie in modifying the configuration file: site_config.py from which the developers say I should:

> Check this file and edit it in such a way that it matches your build
>   environment, the targets you want to compile and where do you want to
>   install them.

Firstly, I tried to install boost,itbb, scons and numpy/scipy library via apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
sudo apt-get install scons
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev
```

I'm not sure if those are the correct versions, but that's what I could find after researching a bit.

The next step is to adapt the entries in the configuration file, but I find it very difficult (actually I have not much of a clue) to find out WHERE all those directories are after installing the above-mentioned libraries are or how to adapt this configuration file respectively:

```
# Use 'release' for speed, 'debug' for debugging.
COMPILE_MODE='release'
# Use one or both of the following words: 'standalone' for 
# building the standalone executable, 'python' for building
# the python module
COMPILE_TARGETS='standalone python'
# Where the boost library is installed. I expect an 'include'
# and a 'lib' dir below.
BOOST_ROOT='/opt/boost_1_47_0/'
# The prefix of the python installation. This is used for deducing
# include directories and lib path of python
PYTHON_PREFIX="/usr/"
# The python's version. Used for deducing include directories and 
# library name of python.
PYTHON_VERSION ="2.7"
# Where the Intel threading building blocks is installed. I expect
# and 'include' and a 'lib' directory below this one.
TBB_PREFIX="/home/alcides/programming/projects/sci_python/prx"
# The executable for the c++ compiler to use. 
COMPILER_NAME="g++-4.6"
# The place where numpy is installed. I expect the directories 
# 'core/include' and 'numarray/include' below.
NUMPY_PREFIX="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/"

# Where you sould like the standalone program to be installed
GECMI_PROGRAM_INSTALL_AT='/usr/local/bin'
# Where you would like the shared library to be installed. This
# library is used by both the python module and the standalone 
# program.
GECMI_LIB_INSTALL_AT='/usr/local/lib'
# Where would you like to have the module installed, for the 
# target 'InstallPythonModule'. A dll file called gecmi.{dllext}
# is installed there. 
PYTHON_MODULE_INSTALL_AT='/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
```

The tip of the authors points to modifying the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, but didn't help me much either:

> You can get messages of the kind error while loading shared libraries
>   if the dependencies are not correctly installed. In that case, you
>   might want to fiddle with the commands locate and the environment
>   variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or the equivalents in your operating system
>   of choice.

I tried to use whereis and locate, but not sure if that works. For example when I use `whereis boost` or l`ocate boost` I find a lot of directories, but no directory like `boost/include` or `boost/lib` which seems to be expected by the config file. For numpy there is no `numarray/include` folder asf.

So basically I was wondering how a linux power user would find all the necessary paths and directories and figure out how to get this code to run (or if some of you could run the code). I'm also thankful for some further information/tutorial/advices on how to get more familiar with solving such problems.

thanks!

Comment: Use `whereis $programName` to find where they are.

Comment: Yes I tried that, but not sure if this is correct. For example when I use {whereis boost} or locate boost I find a lot of directories, but no directory like boost/include or boost/lib which seems to be expected by the config file.  For numpy there is no inumarray/include folder asf.